# Dynamically inserting a row into the middle of a table to be posted back for model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a simple `<table>` of rows using `DropDownFor` and other elements.

On the page these appear as `<somelement name='MyModel.MyArray[0]'>`, `<somelement name='MyModel.MyArray[1]'>`, `<somelement name='MyModel.MyArray[2]'>` etc. on each row.

If I wanted to insert a row into the middle of my list, for example this is a 'todo list' and I want to insert an item at the top, then it will mess with the MVC model binding because I would have to somehow go through and increment the values so the first row would have to be changed to `name='MyModel.MyArray[1]'` etc.

This seems like a real pain to do. I am wondering if there's a better way to handle inserting a row into a list dynamically so that when posted it maps nicely to the model.

Technically I see no reason why MVC needs to know the index of the item.

Is there a better way to do this, or perhaps using MVC model binding with `DropDownFor` etc.  is not the best method?

Comment: do you want to dynamic insert the row in frontent(with js) or backend? But I think you may need to re-create the object and bind again for this case

Comment: ideally, in javascript, so there isn't a page reload when adding a row.

Comment: for js,i think you need re-generate the index should be ok